# Would you modernise Ætheling as Etheling, Aetheling or Atheling? Why?

Tags: old-english, middle-english, ligature

Various modernised spellings exist for Old English words containing the letter Æ and æ for example Ætheling can be modernised as Etheling, Aetheling or Atheling.

Is there a reason to prefer one modern spelling over the others when not using the actual Æ/æ letters?

P.S. A friend of mine intends to give their newborn baby girl an Old English middle name (specifically Æthelflæd) and it would not be possible to put the Æ character in her passport, so they are stuck between the two most common modernised spellings (namely Ethelfled and Aethelflaed) while also knowing sometimes Æthel is modernised as Athel as in Athelstan, and they were just deciding between these.

Comment: You need to edit your question to explain why, and in what circumstances, this change might be made: Are you teaching Old English to students? Are you translating? Are you writing lightweight historical fiction? (I assume that you have already discounted the convenience of "AE" being on a keyboard, while "Æ" is not.)

Comment: The Latin spelling of one of the most prestigious encyclopaedias in the world: Encyclopædia Britannica is today often spelled as *Encyclop**e**dia*.  The modern spelling for fœtus is either foetus or fetus  depending on which country you were born. Why not use a dictionary?

Comment: The evolution of *æ* is summarised [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Old_English#Changes_leading_up_to_Middle_and_Modern_English). But I'm not sure if that's what you're actually asking. You could look at the most common way *æ* evolved, or the way *ætheling* might have evolved, or the most common modern spelling of *ætheling*, or how other *æ* words are spelt. However I don't think words like *encyclopedia* are good guides as they don't come from Old English but came into English much later.

Comment: @Greybeard Thank you for your suggestion I have edited the question to provide more relevant details!

Answer (score 1):

I personally always write "mediaeval" because that's how I learnt it and the spellchecker lets me do it. As long as other people can understand it, why not? Mediaeval and medieval mean the same thing to everyone.

**But** it hinders search algorithms. If you are writing academic papers or similar, which are going to be accessed by many people and need to be searchable, you need to use the standard spelling within your community. Also, someone less well-versed might think that Ætheling, Etheling, Aetheling and Atheling are four different people.

So you need to set or find the standard and keep to it. Or at least include a footnote or glossary item covering all alternative spellings.

Comment: *medi(a)eval* was [reportedly](https://www.etymonline.com/word/medieval?ref=etymonline_crossreference) coined in 1825 from Latin roots, so it's not necessarily a good guide for Old English spelling.

Comment: I had thought of "mediaeval" as a Britishism, but it's actually only even somewhat common in India, according to Google Trends: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?q=mediaeval,medieval

Comment: Not only the spelling but also the pronunciation has changed. People (on television) no longer say "medi-eval", they say "medival". Which bothers me, but then I am just a reactionary old codger.